# excel date format won't change

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

some cells of my excel won't change the date format(they're left aligned in the column).
I've tried everything: copied to notepad and back, text to column, changed the format using the format option (obviously), used DATEVALUE: returns !VALUE#.
I've spent hours trying to change that format and am not rich enough to throw my laptop.

```
|      AR    |
|------------|
| 1995-12-02 |
| 25/04/1989 |
| 25/04/1994 |
| 15/05/1994 |
| 13/06/1980 |
| 1981-02-04 |
| 1995-01-06 |
```

[image]
if this helps... evaluation of error on using DATEVALUE shows that the cell contains a constant..

Comment: Left aligned indicates it could be formatted as text. Is it in the correct format for your locality?  Try multiplying the date by 1 or adding 0 `=A1*1`.

Comment: i tried the DATEFORMAT method for that, in case they are formatted as text but it shows !VALUE# (incorrect data type)

Comment: cells with - are changing the format as desired while those with / aren't

Comment: Have you tried multiply by 1?  Or Find/Replace to change `/` to `-`?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook i copied it to notepad changed all / to - and then again copied it to the excel column again when i change the format to YYYY-mm-dd all only the cells that were changing earlier, responded to that and all others were still dd-mm-YYYY. Lemme try multiply by 1

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook multiplying by 1 again shows !VALUE# in those cells. Aint there any standard way to convert maybe from text type to date type (Except datevalue as it shows !VALUE#)

Comment: Not sure if this will work but try this formula:  `=IF(IFERROR(FIND("/",A1),A1)>5,A1,RIGHT($A1,4) & "-" & MID($A1,4,2) & "-" & LEFT($A1,2))`.  It should change _25/04/1989_ to _1989-04-25_  or maybe `=IF(IFERROR(FIND("/",A1),A1)>5,A1,DATEVALUE(RIGHT($A1,4) & "-" & MID($A1,4,2) & "-" & LEFT($A1,2)))` (just added DATEVALUE to reformatted date).

Comment: You could try the following formulas: `=TEXT(A1,"DD/MM/YY")` or `=TEXT(CONCATENATE(RIGHT(A1,2),"/",MID(A1,6,2),"/",LEFT(A1,4)),"DD/MM/YY")` or try combining this with @Darren Bartrup-Cook formula

Comment: An alternative to throwing a laptop is to buy a cheap keyboard, plug it in, use it, next time things don't go to plan, you can smash the keyboard up (If you decide to throw the keyboard, then make sure you unplug it first!)

Comment: @5202456 nah! i rather prefer playing counter strike and breaking some heads XD XD but it is stuck in a update so nowhere to take off my frustration...

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook that second formula just worked ^ ^ (still shows !VALUE# in some cells tho).... it gave me 32623 and then i changed the format to YYYY-MM-DD and it worked..... is there any easier way tho ?? XD

Comment: @5202456 that text formula (first one) just gives the same type of cell again and second one gives 89//1/25/0

Comment: The remaining errors must be formatted slightly differently.  Could you give an example of what the those dates look like?  I find the easiest way to get dates correct is send it back to the person who sent it to you and tell them to be consistent... not always an option though.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific case, following workaround will do:

[image]

```
=IF(ISERR(SEARCH("-",D2)),DATE(RIGHT(D2,4),MID(D2,4,2),LEFT(D2,2)),DATE(LEFT(D2,4),MID(D2,6,2),LEFT(D2,2)))
```

Comment: worked for some but for others like: 13/06/1980 it is returning bad results, in this case 2985-07-21

Comment: why don't spreadsheet softwares have a direct method of converting cells from text type to date? ppl have been facing this issue for quite long time right? in most cases one or other fix has worked for em.... but none is working for me :(

Comment: @akshaysharma Because then everyone would have to format their dates the same way and then we'd have "date formatting wars" and we've got enough to be fighting over already without adding _mm-dd-yyyy_ into the mix. :)

Comment: Normally, you face the issue when you open spreadsheet, created on the machine with different regional date/time settings, so you find in your timestamp/data column some cells recognized as data and the others, recognized as something else (text string, if you're lucky enough), so there shouldn't be 3+ timestamps/dates formats. Even if it is, you may branch if statement even further to catch all possible formats. Alternatively, you may play around with your system regional settings so that your data recognized by excel as timestamp/date.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Nothing seems to work so i finally used a workaround.... replaced all - with / in all cells... used text to column to separate in 3 columns with / delimiter and then merged em in year month day column order in a new column... i know it is a noob approach XD but nothing seems to work and all i need fron this data is to convert to csv and upload to database.. so m ok till then i guess XD

Comment: That's not a noob approach.  It's a one off and sounds like a quick way to do it - perfect result in my view.